# Ext JS 2.3 - Previous values in fields displaying- it's like an browser auto fill selections but different

Tags: javascript, extjs, browser, autofill, auto

i clicked on Destination Zip field and a list appeared which is not expected.
i used autoComplete:False but still not working.Need Help.

[image]

Comment: How is it different from [browser autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried autocomplete as false but it did not work for my project if i set these settings off for my browser then it will work for all projects and i want it specifically for my project.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1kqb.png)